# SQL count number partition by id and displaying only top 3 of each id

Tags: sql

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhP0t.png)

Hi everyone,

i tried attempting this SQL question but am facing difficulty in this question. particularly counting the number of deals and summing the total deals per merchant. and then i also do not know how to display only the first 3 entries as well.

should this problem be resolved via the partition by function? i have no idea how to resolve this.

subsequently how do i display only the top 3?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that homework related questions are expected to prove some extra effort.